# Using the Instagram API to search for users by name in Sandbox mode

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to use the Instagram API to search for users I have invited into Sandbox mode using the following endpoint - https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=Jack&access_token=#######.

Unless I use the username of one of the sandbox invitees as the query, it does not give me any results. I have tried using all variations on the names as queries. Does anyone know why this may be the case? Does the API not allow searching by name? I am operating under the *public_content* scope and the invitees have public profiles.

Answer (score 0):

In sandbox mode you will only see user results from your sandbox users.

So if you search for your username or one of your sandbox users, then you will just see that user in results. Once you go live mode, you will see all results.

Comment: I was trying to use their name not their username to find the sandbox users. Is searching by name not supported?

Comment: it is supported in live mode, not sure about sandbox mode.